# Return a read-only double pointer

Tags: c++, constants, double-pointer

I want to a member variable, which is a double pointer. The object, the double pointer points to shall not be modified from outside the class.

My following try yields an 
*"invalid conversion from ‘std::string**’ to ‘const std::string**’"*

```cpp
class C{

public:
    const std::string **getPrivate(){
        return myPrivate;
    }

private:
    std::string **myPrivate;
};
```

- Why is the same construct valid if i use just a simple pointer `std::string *myPrivate`
- What can i do to return a read-only double pointer?

  Is it good style to do an explicit cast `return (const std::string**) myPrivate`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, i edited my post. Its the string itself that shall not be modified.

Comment: Thinking of them as "double pointers" may be the root of your problem. The term "double pointer" is one I never encountered until I came across SO, and I'd be kind of interested to know which nitwit (not necessarily on SO) originated it.

Comment: Also, with regards to your last sentence, it's rarely good style to do an explicit cast.  Casting may be necessary but is never stylish.

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const std::string * const *getPrivate(){
    return myPrivate;
}
```

The trouble with const std::string ** is that it allows the caller to modify one of the pointers, which isn't declared as const.  This makes both the pointer and the string class itself const.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be *really* picky :

```
class C {

public:
    std::string const* const* const getPrivate(){
        return myPrivate;
    }

private:
    std::string **myPrivate;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are very rare cases in c++ when a raw pointer (even less for a double pointer) is really needed, and your case doesn't seams to be one of them. A proper way would be to return a value or a reference, like this :

```
class C{

public:
    const std::string& getPrivate() const
    {
        return myPrivate;
    }

private:
    std::string myPrivate;
};
```

Comment: This would have been my preferred way as well - especially with a string, but I didn't know if the poster had some other type that might have actually required this...

Comment: Perhaps i should have written my Motivation: I want to have access to an array with two indices x[0][1], so i created an array of pointers. But although it might have been possible to change my code in another position i wanted to know how to handle "double-pointers" or hower a pro calls pointers-to-pointers.